# Mobile reports custom url in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, sql-server-mobile

I am trying to pass a drillthrough custom url in SSRS Mobile Reports using values from my database, the problem is that my value contains special characters like "/" which look to be converting to `%2F` causing the hyperlink to break. Is there any way to pass the literal value without conversion?